# JQuery Mobile: inline data-role="page" javascript being retain when page is released from DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Using this call `<a href="deleteDialog.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" id='deleteDialog'>Delete</a>` to get the following dialog page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="deleteCompanyDialog">
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#deleteButton").live("click", function() {
        alert("this alert increments");

});

</script>

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>

    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Delete Company</h1>
        <p id="message"></p>
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="deleteButton" >Sounds good</a>       
        <a href="company.jsp" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

seems to retain the `live("click"..` binding from any previous calls to this dialog and then binds the `live` call again.  So if I call the page 4 separate times, on the forth dialog page call it will popup 4 alert screens.  Is there a way to have the javascript still be within `data-role="page"` so it can load with ajax but not increment the "live" binding. I tried `$("#deleteCompanyDialog").live("pagecreate"...` as well as `pageload` (a long shot) which does not work either.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: data-role="Dialog" is at equal position as data-role="page", so if you try to put it inside a page, it won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `.live()`, use `.bind()` and place your JavaScript in a delegated event handler:

```
<div data-role="page" id="deleteCompanyDialog">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Dialog</h1>

    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Delete Company</h1>
        <p id="message"></p>
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="deleteButton" >Sounds good</a>       
        <a href="company.jsp" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).delegate("#deleteCompanyDialog", "pageinit", function() {
    $("#deleteButton").bind('click', function () {
        alert("this alert DOES NOT increment");
    });
});

</script>
</div>
```

This is like using `$(function () {});` but for jQuery Mobile. The `pageinit` event will fire when the page is initialized (happens once per pseudo-page) and the `.bind()` function call will only bind to elements present in the DOM. When you use `.live()` it doesn't bind to the actual element, it binds to the `document` element, which does not get removed when you navigate away from the dialog (so each time you show the dialog you add another delegated event handler).

Comment: Using bind instead of live worked.  thank you for the detailed answer

Comment: Really wonderful answer Jasper; you deserve much more clout for this great response! As a follow-up, I noticed that an alert _inside_ the delegate (by itself) would get fired extra times (once per page visit) when using the browser back button for navigation and then re-entering the page. Is there a sanctioned way to only have javascript that is only fired once in this scenario? It's as though we need a function that knows that it has already been included in the page and subsequent requests could ignore it. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Update: I resolved my trials by following the '`off` before `on`' principle! Thanks for your thoughts and contributions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067259/jquery-mobile-click-firing-multiple-times-on-new-page-visit

Comment: @veeTrain By default, jQuery Mobile removes pages from the DOM that were brought into the DOM via AJAX. This is done to conserve memory. So if you hit the back button and jQuery Mobile removed the previous page, it has to re-gather the page and initialize it, which will fire the `pageinit` function. You can stop this by adding the `data-cache="true"` attribute to any `data-role="page"` element that gets brought into the DOM via AJAX.