# Have to press a button twice for a response Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a button that is being created with the following code

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#ratesection').html(vote).trigger('create');},
   400
);
```

The button is created fine and works however it only works if it is touched or clicked twice? After pressing it twice any time I press it again after it functions as expected. Anyone has any idea as to why this is happening.

**EDIT:**
Below is the code which the trigger is creating

```
vote = "<div id='mobiscroll'></div><button id='rate' data-inline='true'>Rate D Chune</button><span id='ratetext'>N/A</span><input type='hidden' id='rating' name='rating' />"
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the HTML as requested and the click function

Click Function

```
$(document).on('click', '#rate', function () {
             $('#mobiscroll').mobiscroll('show'); });
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="content" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-grid-a" id="ratesection"></div> 
            </div>
```

Comment: can you show what the create function is doing?

Comment: its creating a button will edit my code

Comment: show us ur HTML. what is `ratesSection`? is it a `div` with `data-role=page`?

Comment: and show us ur `click` function for the button

Comment: append the button, remove `.trigger('create')` and use `$('#rate').button();` after its appended.

Comment: firing tice is a comming problem, you need to unbind the click event again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067259/jquery-mobile-click-firing-multiple-times-on-new-page-visit

Comment: @zyrex it fires on second click, not firing twice.

Comment: This code should resolve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Mn63p/

Comment: @Omar tried your code and the issue is still occurring the first click does nothing and from the second click it works as expected. This is the only button that is doing this. If I don't insert the button using ajax then it works from the first click.

Comment: @passionateCoder html and click function added to the originial question

Comment: @KernElliott can you post a jsfiddle reproducing the same problem? This way we can debug the problem in a better way