# Submit twice using Jquery + JQM

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have this code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });

</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

I have a simple POST which I trigger simply even via console like this:

```
$('#eTicketForm').submit()
```

my MVC post is:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Identification", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "eTicketForm", data_ajax="false" }))
{
}
```

For some reason the post is called twice. Is there any known issue with JQM + Jquery in different versions?

Comment: I just call it with : $('#eTicketForm').submit() and still I get the double call

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067259/jquery-mobile-click-firing-multiple-times-on-new-page-visit